# Should big edits be approved?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I recently suggested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4011521), and it was rejected. I'm sure that the reviewers would agree that it was a helpful edit (whether or not it was to be approved) if they had dived deeper into it and looked at both OP's site, and my JSFiddle link. The question was pretty simple ("How to center text in a `<select>`"), but OP had provided a lot of extra code which probably made it look like I was decapitating the question.

Should this have been approved? If so, how can we make sure it will be in the future? What can I do to convince people that I'm not deleting important stuff? Should there be a dispute-edit button?

---

And YES, the code *was in the question*. The JSFiddle link was just there for convenience, but the question would still have all necessary information without it. Keep in mind that there are only *2 lines* of CSS in question, both of which were mentioned inline. Yes, there is something called english, people. A code block shouldn't change anything. [UXSE question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51923/short-and-concise-or-real-world-example-for-a-question-on-stack-exchange) on readability vs examples.

Comment: I agree that it should have been approved. What you can do at the moment is make a note in the summary, and apart from that, just trust the reviewers.

Comment: @minitech I did say "Got rid of the useless code".

Comment: @bjb568 I downvoted because I disagree with the fact that you think this was a good edit.  You basically removed everything from the question.  2 months ago, the question you left would have been closed for "minimal understanding" because you left no evidence except for a fiddle that the OP tried anything.

Comment: @psubsee I removed everything unnecessary, yes. What? Are you blaming _me_ for a flaw in the system? (Yes I would agree with your second sentence) Minimal understanding? That's there. The question is a great one, and I don't think it (or any other question) requires an example of what was tried.

Comment: @bjb568: Questions shouldn't necessarily be stripped down to their bones. Is a code block necessary? No. Does it help some people? Yes. The example initially given may not have been the greatest, but one *was included*, and edits should avoid changing the author's intention.

Comment: @icktoofay You are contradicting yourself. Questions should be stripped down to their bones. Is adding a code block a rational decision? Of course not. There is not enough code. Don't tell me people can't read 26 words, but the answer was too short. And no, the author's intention was not changed.

Comment: @bjb568: I'm contradicting myself? I'm saying providing a concrete example in the question as a code block is helpful, if not necessary. The author's intention was to have one. You removed it.

Comment: No, it's not helpful. How about this, to end this you can go ask a question about that on UXSE. I guarantee you, adding code bloat in a block (because 26 words (such as "I", "a", "get" and "want") are much too hard to read) helps no-one.

Comment: I'm not sure why you bothered to ask here, when you clearly don't want to listen to the feedback you're getting.

Comment: @Ken Not if they go against common sense, no.

Comment: That's not true. It's "not if they don't agree with your point of view", which is quite wrong. But if you don't want to hear them, **don't ask for them in the first place**.

Comment: I would've rejected that edit too. Please, research here on Meta and the [help] how editing (and Fiddle links) works.

Comment: @bjb568 the edit was rejected, the reasons are given, it's one rejected edit - really not a big deal, move on..

Comment: @bjb568: Regardless of the issue, your arrogance towards the others here did not help with anything, except for perhaps receiving more downvotes (rants usually do cause this).

Comment: @bjb568 this is Stack Overflow.  The opinion of UX.SE is virtually irrelevant.

Comment: @bjb568 my point was nothing more than the SO community has decided what they want to consider as acceptable edits.  Radical changes to questions like that are heavily frowned upon.  It doesn't really matter what the UX community thinks (although some may also be SO users).  If you want to make these kinds of edits then stop complaining and go get 2K rep so you can make them and you don't have to worry about rejected edits, just the occasional rollback

Comment: Hi! Feel free to be opinionated, but politeness is not optional.

Comment: @psubsee Last time I checked edits are supposed to be helpful. Are you telling me that I should refrain from being helpful? Are you telling me that I can't ask a question on UXSE because it "doesn't matter", even tho somehow your comment (an answer to my UX question) is perfectly fine?

Comment: @bjb568 you can ask over there (looks like it is on topic), but my point is it won't change a thing.  Whether or not you or I or anyone else like it, this is how the community on SO has decided they want suggedted edits to be handled.

Comment: Hi! That’s enough.

Comment: Just resuggest the edit and hope it gets reviewed by more "open-minded" users. I've had some edits rejected but that was because they they think code spacing was too minor

Comment: @puretppc Oh, all right.

Answer (score 8):

You deleted the code included within the question and moved it all to a fiddle, which is discouraged; all relevant code is supposed to be included in the question, and a fiddle is only a supplementary measure. The loss of code within the question itself would make me reject the edit.

I would have instead removed the irrelevant CSS rules like `font-face` and all the colors while preserving the rest of their structure, cleaned up the prose in the question (like the drop-down menu → `<select>` change you did), and replaced the link to their web site with a fiddle containing the modified code in the question.

Comment: What? There were 2 lines of CSS remaining, both of which were mentioned in the question. "with a _set width_" and "_text-align: center_ works in FF, but not Chrome or IE".

Comment: @bjb568: You *mentioned* what was done in the question, but *showed* what was done only in the fiddle. It would be preferable to leave a code block in the question.

Comment: Why? Everything needed was conveyed. If I asked that question, it shouldn't have been flagged with "unclear what you're asking". It's clear enough, everything needed to be communicated was communicated. to pull it out and put it in a block does not change anything.

Comment: What if the fiddle is deleted @bjb568? The code needs to remain in the post for documenting purposes so any user in the future can make use of it without having to worry about any external resource still being available. Without the code, the post would be useless.

Comment: @Sly The code was in the question. The fiddle was just for an example. In any case, that doesn't match the reject reason.

Comment: @bjb568: Maybe it's not *necessary* to pull it out into a code block, but it sure helps comprehension. Maybe someone is feeling lazy and wants to just look at the code blocks rather than read the text. Is that their fault? Perhaps, but there's no harm in making it easier for potential answerers to get the gist of the situation with a concrete example. As for the reject reason, your edit does look rather radical. While it may not be *necessary* to have the specific “$250-$500 Per Month” options, it's closer to the original, and I think that would be more well-received.

Comment: Um… the text was 26 words long. A kindergartener could read that with no difficulty. If you are going to complain, go to the 10-long-paragraphs question. "X$ Per Month" options will _add to the 26 words_, not take away. You shouldn't reject an edit because they change some text that wasn't necessary anyway.

Comment: @bjb568: People are lazy. Can they read it? Yes. But why make them if they don't need to? Your edit makes it harder to skim and removes concrete details that, while not necessary, give something people can grasp, and that's a valuable thing.

Comment: You make zero sense. *It's small enough that they don't need to skim it!* Details? Details describe the question better, not worse.

Comment: @bjb568: It's prose. Sometimes I'll skip over it and just read the code to get a gist of what the question's about without thinking too hard about it. Without any code blocks, I have to read, and that's not something I always want to do, no matter how short it is. Certainly, a code block is not appropriate for all questions, but I feel it is appropriate here, and evidently the original author did, too.

Comment: Ok, discussion closed until somebody from UXSE says something.

Comment: What does UXSE have to do with this? You raised a question and it's pretty clear from the feedback (votes and answers) that the community in general disagrees with your assessment. Now you're taking that and trying to cram your point of view down our throats with insults. Take a step back and look at what is being said to you, and come back with a constructive response please.

Comment: @Chris This question (at least the part we're debating) is primarily about UX. Is it better to provide context, or be short and readable? That's the question I asked on UXSE. I do not understand how SO policies or peoples opinions can be more important than basic UX. The fundamental concept of the site is to have good user-gened-content, and nothing should get in the way. While the couple people here might represent the community in some manner, and the "community" here does not happen to like my edit, user experience experts should still chose whether the fundamentals of my edit were good.

Comment: There were multiple questions there, you know. "What can I do to convince people that I'm not deleting important stuff? Should there be a dispute-edit button?"

Comment: I find it quite ironic how you complained about my edit, then you [messed it up](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21653243/revisions) yourself. And of course, I fixed it (plus adding the stuff from my original edit).

Comment: @bjb568: Yes, I did do an edit myself. I did it to demonstrate what I set forth in my answer here, to set a good example. I like your new edit; it clarifies the question further without changing *too* much, avoiding what I saw as the problems of your previous edit.